Bypass 2FA if the SSH key type is "-sk"
I have a server with Google Authentication + PAM set up so it requires a TOTP when connecting to it through SSH. But I would like to make an exception for SSH keys that are stored in a security key, is this possible?
This question made me think that it is possible to have a separate authorized_keys for these exceptions and control this via PAM, but I don't know if it's possible to switch between them.
